# Rounding problem with rspec tests when comparing float arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, testing, rspec, floating-point

There is a method which result I want to check:

```
 result.should  == [1.0,2.0,3.0]
```

But I get an error:

```
   expected: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
        got: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] (using ==)
```

I think the problem in rounding, but I don `t know how compare them, for example with a deviation of 0.1.

Thank you, apneadiving. 
I wrote my own matcher, if it help someone:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_closed_array do |expected, truth|
  match do |actual|
    same = 0
    for i in 0..actual.length-1
      same +=1 if actual[i].round(truth) == expected[i].round(truth)
    end
    same == actual.length
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would be close to #{expected}"
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would not be close to #{expected}"
  end

  description do
    "be a close to #{expected}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use (deprecated since [2.7.0](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/commit/4638609046a120c86d48a0253b471db55a5fd441#diff-a26c79378299c0868d0462d2000c54e204e9b854f1dd772c05e7deb588033ff0R3), removed in [3.0.0](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/commit/a00be5b15dacfae7aa0be68fdd4ccd1ebd2ddf1a#diff-4ac680eeaffa2461320261649ec69d2b543331a37dc7ac88c33de1f77163293c)):

```
 .should be_close
```

Or even:

```
 .should be_within
```

Ref here http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.4.0/RSpec/Matchers

Comment: Thank you, I know about these methods, but I do not know how apply them to array. I have iterate each value? Because this line         result.should be_close([1.0,2.0,3.0], 0.1), does not work.

Comment: Mmmm... Don't know. You'd better create your own matcher, it's pretty straight

Comment: Since RSpec 3 only `be_within` is implemented: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/3.1.0/RSpec/Matchers#be_within-instance_method vs http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.4.0/RSpec/Matchers#be_close-instance_method