# Random RSpec failures comparing Floats (Eq matcher)

Tags: ruby, rspec, matcher

I'm not even sure where to begin here.  Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I don't even know what to search for or what this particular issue is called.

Randomly, and not all that often, a test in my RSpec suite will fail and I'll get an error like this:

```
expected: 0.69
     got: 0.69 (0.69e0)

(compared using ==)
```

The RSpec code is comparing two Floats, from two different models, that should be the same value when the spec is done.  Is there a way to reproduce this in a command console?  I've tried the obvious stuff (below) but I am honestly at a loss.  If I rerun the test a dozen times, I can't reproduce the issue.

```
0.69 == 0.69e0 => true
0.69 == 0.69 => true
6.9e-1 == 0.69 => true
```

Comment: I don't know a way to reproduce it, but you always use `.round` in the tests.

Comment: comparing floats is hard :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855944/rounding-problem-with-rspec-tests-when-comparing-float-arrays

Comment: @maxpleaner - these tests do use `.round` ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general problem testing floating point numbers. I always convert them to strings for comparison when using RSpec:

```
expect(float.to_s).to eq '0.69'
```

Comment: Its almost too simple of a solution.  I also wonder if I should be using BigDecimal in my tests instead - as to at least stay with a Numeric type.  `float.to_d` should also work?

Comment: I have a lot of BigDecimals in my specs, but always have to call `to_s` on BigDecimal results too.

Answer (score 11):

When testing floating point numbers, I recommend you use RSpec's `be_within` [matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-8/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher).

Example:

```rb
expect(my_float).to be_within(0.01).of(0.69)
```

You should choose a resolution that makes sense for your use case. (0.001, 0.0001, etc.)